# Unable to retrieve annotation via ProceedingJoinPoint

Tags: annotations, aop, aspectj, spring-aop

I would like to retrieve an annotation from AOP join point. I am able to get the annotation by reflection, but unable to do so with ProceedingJoinPoint.

If the method isn't annotated with Profile, the advise would not be invoked... but inside the advise, it couldn't locate the annotation.

**By ProceedingJoinPoint**

```java
@Around("@annotation(com.annotation.Profile)")
public Object logAround(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
    Signature signature = joinPoint.getSignature();
    String methodName = signature.toString();
    Method method = ((MethodSignature) signature).getMethod();

    Profile profile = method.getAnnotation(Profile.class);

    // profile is null here...
    // ......

}
```

**By reflection directly**

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException {
    Method method = SampleServiceImpl.class.getMethod("getTicket", String.class);
    System.out.println(method.getClass().toString());
    System.out.println(method.getAnnotation(Profile.class));
}
```

**My Annotation**

```java
@Documented
@Retention(value = RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface Profile {
    public long skipCount();
    public long sampleSize();
}
```

**My Annotated method**

```java
@Override
@Cacheable("test")
@Transactional
@Profile(skipCount = 100, sampleSize = 100)
public Tickets getTicket(String ticketId) {
    return sampleDao.getTicket(ticketId);
}
```

**My POM**

```xml
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <jdk.version>1.8</jdk.version>
    <spring.version>4.1.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <aspectj.version>1.8.3</aspectj.version>
</properties>

<!-- Spring AOP + AspectJ -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need for reflection, it is much easier. You can bind the annotation to an advice parameter:

```java
@Around("@annotation(profileAnnotation)")
public Object logAround(Profile profileAnnotation, ProceedingJoinPoint thisJoinPoint) throws Throwable {
    System.out.println(thisJoinPoint + " - " +  profileAnnotation);
    // (...)
    Object result = thisJoinPoint.proceed();
    // (...)
    return result;
}
```

The console output could be something like this:

```
execution(void de.scrum_master.app.Application.main(String[])) - @de.scrum_master.app.Profile(skipCount=5, sampleSize=11)
```

Comment: Thanks. With GCLIB on, I am able to get the annotation from the code I shown before. May I know if there is any drawback for enabling GCLIB?

Comment: Do you mean in comparison to Java dynamic proxies? Usually, the Java proxies only work for interfaces, CGLIB also works for classes you need to proxy without interfaces. Otherwise I do not have much practical experience with either of them because I only use native AspectJ which does not need any proxies at all. Spring AOP is just proxy-based "AOP lite" and not my choice.

Comment: The order of the method argument should be reversed, I have make an amendment on the provided code.

Comment: I do not understand your comment. I do not see any edits in your question, my own edit is the last one. And what was reversed? How would it affect my answer?

Comment: The jointPoint should be the first argument of the method.

Comment: No, the last one, see my sample console output. Have you even tried?

Comment: Yup, I tried. It only works if I put joint point as the first argument, it throws exception otherwise. Not sure if that's related to the version that I used

Comment: I was using AspectJ 1.8.x, and you? AspectJ or Spring AOP? Which version?

Comment: <spring.version>4.1.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <aspectj.version>1.8.3</aspectj.version>

Comment: But is Spring configured to use Spring AOP (usually configured via the `<aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>` or `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy` setting) or full AspectJ (usually via `<context:load-time-weaver/>` or `@EnableLoadTimeWeaving`)?